# Cosmos DB permissions on multiple resources

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I found the following document: [CosmosDB grant permission to multiple resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447095/cosmosdb-grant-permission-to-multiple-resources)
The answer there states that after the resource token broker gets the Permissions feed of the user and sends it back to client:

```
FeedResponse<Permission> permFeed = await client.ReadPermissionFeedAsync(UriFactory.CreateUserUri("dbid", " userId")); 

List<Permission> permList = permFeed.ToList();
```

The client app can then initialize an instance of the DocumentClient class and pass the list (provided that it will deserialize the Json to `List<Permission>`).

```
var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var permissions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Permission>>(jsonString);
var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), permisions);
```

The problem that I have is that the `Permission` class has a `Token` property that has only a *getter* and no *setter* exists. The following source code is from *Microsoft.Azure.Documents* namespace.

```
namespace Microsoft.Azure.Documents
{
  public class Permission : Resource
  {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "resource")]
    public string ResourceLink { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "resourcePartitionKey")]
    public PartitionKey ResourcePartitionKey { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof (StringEnumConverter))]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "permissionMode")]
    public PermissionMode PermissionMode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_token")]
    public string Token { get; }    <------------------------------------- HERE
  }
}
```

As such, trying to serialize the `Token` field, the value copied is null.

Anyone has any solution for that?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are doing this using the old v2 SDK? Cosmos just recently released support for Azure AD auth with RBAC support. This is MUCH better than using the old users and permissions model. But it's v3 SDK only.

Comment: I updated the NuGet to 2.14 and I seen the `Token` now has a private setter, the value gets copied but it still doesn't work `(The client does not have any valid token for the requested resource dbs/UsersDB/colls/UserItems.`. Could you give me a reference to the new doc?

Comment: Basically I use the example from TodoDocumentDBAuth of Xamarin which is quite outdated... :(

Comment: Yes. That example has not been updated in years. If you are able to have users auth using Azure AD via their devices this will be much easier to use. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac

Comment: Yes. I have seen a video of you & Thomas Weiss on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEzW2D-tshM). Still have trouble to understand how I can have thousands of users accessing specific items on the Cosmos DB with RBAC via their mobiles. What I am trying to do is having users connected (with EasyAuth), and have specific access to collections or items on the collections. eg. a user shouldn't be allowed to alter the profile of an other user, only read it. On the other hand it should have write permission to his/her profile, etc.

Comment: Basically, I need fine grained permissions to access items of the DB if I intend to do direct Cosmos DB access from a mobile app and not via an Azure Function or some kind of Rest API (in which cases I can write the authorization logic inside the functions).